# HEVC Intra Prediction Module

Tags: hevc, video-codecs

I have been working on HEVC Intra Prediction for the past few weeks. I have understood the concept of the Module however, still a little skeptical with respect to the Rough Mode Decision process. Can someone give a clear basics as to the angles defined in each directional mode. I would be really thankful for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think this might be helpful. I have given some information with respect to the 35 angles and 35 modes. This would answer your doubts.

Horizontal Modes

```
All Horizontal Modes  - 2  3  4  5  6  7 8 9 10 11 12 13  14  15  16  17  
All Horizontal Angles - 32 26 21 17 13 9 5 2  0 -2 -5 -9 -13 -17 -21 -26
```

Positive Angles

```
All Horizontal Positive Modes  - 2  3  4  5  6  7 8 9 10   
All Horizontal Positive Angles - 32 26 21 17 13 9 5 2 0
```

Negative Angles

```
All Horizontal Negative Modes  - 11 12 13  14  15  16  17  
All Horizontal Negative Angles - -2 -5 -9 -13 -17 -21 -26
```

Vertical Modes

```
All Vertical Modes  -  18  19  20  21  22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34  
All Vertical Angles - -32 -26 -21 -17 -13 -9 -5 -2 0  2  5  9  13 17 21 26 32
```

Negative Angles

```
All vertical Negative Modes  -  18  19  20  21  22 23 24 25  
All vertical Negative Angles - -32 -26 -21 -17 -13 -9 -5 -2
```

Positive Angles

```
All Vertical Positive Modes  - 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34  
All Vertical Positive Angles - 0  2  5  9  13 17 21 26 32
```

Comment: thank you for this information. Yes, it does clarify my doubts to a certain extent.

Comment: if you can help with any other content which will help me in understanding of Intra Prediction, any suggestion will be helpful for me.

Comment: @Niraj, considering you are a complete no-vice in HEVC. I can refer a book which is the best for starters. Here's the link for the book  http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319068947

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I thought if I upvote your question and accept it, your answer is correct. But for some reason I am not able to do so, I apologize though, it gives me some less reputation or something which I am new to it but really thank you for your help. Will upvote once I get some repu